# Auto-ionization equilibrium of water shifted with acid-base addition?

Tags: acid-base, water, ionization-energy

Adding acids or bases to water, so that either pH or pOH decreases independently of the other, will that affect the auto-ionization of water? For example, pure water + auto-ionized state, with some base added to remove some protons, will it auto-ionize a bit more (create more H+ and OH-) or a bit less (remove some H+ and OH-)?

Comment: @ed v I am thinking about what happens when a tiny amount of _ammonia_ is added to the water.  Ammonia takes away hydrogen ions rather than putting in hydroxide ions, so it actually _increases_ the extent of water autoionization as the water chases the hydrogen ion ansorption.

Comment: The autoionization with ammonia is the hydroxide ions which came entirely from water molecules, and there are more of those than in pure water.  There are fewer solvated hydrogen ions, true, because the ammonia consumed some of them, whereas it didn't react with the hydroxide ions from the water.

Comment: I think you misread what I mean. I'm thinking of the auto-ionization independently from the reactions with _other_ acids and bases (water itself can be viewed as an amfolyte, capable of giving away both a proton and a hydroxide ion. ) Then, if the addition of other acids or bases will tend to increase or decrease the auto-ionization.

Comment: Addition of acids or bases to pure water will always decrease the auto-ionization.

Comment: @Rafiki  As acidobasic equilibrium reactions of acids and bases share the common ions with the equilibrium reaction of water autodissociation, you cannot consider them separately.  Each equilibrium honors its equilibrium constant. Shift in ion concentrations due one equilibrium affects all other equilibriums sharing this ion.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you write the reaction.

> For example, pure water + auto-ionized state, with some base added to remove some protons, will it auto-ionize a bit more (create more H+ and OH-) or a bit less (remove some H+ and OH-)?

If we call the base $\ce{B}$ and the conjugate acid $\ce{BH+}$, you could write:

$$\ce{B + H3O+ <=> BH+ + H2O}$$

This would mean that you just lost some hydronium ions, and water will ionize a bit more to attain equilibrium with its ions.

Or you could write it like this:

$$\ce{B + H2O <=> BH+ + OH-}$$

This would mean that you just gained some hydroxide ions, and water will ionize a bit less to attain equilibrium with its ions.

**What about adding acid?**

Same story:

$$\ce{AH + H2O <=> A- + H3O+}$$

or

$$\ce{AH + OH- <=> A- + H2O}$$

**Which one is correct?**

Either one is fine. You will arrive at the same equilibrium concentrations if you consider one of the acid/base reactions and water auto-dissociation. Depending on what is the major species and what is the minor species, you can choose one or the other. Or if you can't decide, you can be creative and write:

$$\ce{AH + 1/2 OH- <=> A- + 1/2 H3O+}$$